# I need to prove a formula but not sure where to go from the progress I have made.

Tags: statistics

I need to prove that $P(A) ≤ P(B)$ knowing that $A⊂B $. I also know that $P(A′∩B)+P(A)=P(B)$. How do I go further to prove the formula $P(A) ≤ P(B)$. Thank you.

Comment: $A \cap B = A$ and $P(A' \cap B) \geq 0$. What can you say now?

Comment: I can say that $P(A'∩B) + P(A) = P(B)$ and then $P(A'∩B) ≥ 0$. Where do I go from there. I am not too sure.

Comment: That's it!  Now, because $P(A) = P(B) - P(A' \cap B) $, $P(A)$ has to be smaller than $P(B)$ because you are subtracting a positive number from $P(B)$ to get $P(A)$ ! Do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if you know that $A \subseteq B$, then what do you know about $A \cap B$?